# Searching for a file by content, may involve -exec command and piping 2>

Tags: linux, find, command, exec, stderr

Am presently learning Linux through a virtual environment immersion and have been tasked with finding a file by content. User is root, rwx permissions for all (777 I believe). I have tried many things to no avail but they are all basically rooted in a variation of

```
~$ find / -user root -perm 777 | grep "phrase to be found"
```

So far I've been successful at retrieving tons of permission denied messages. I can't use the sudo command as I don't have the sudo password (virtual environment). It's possible that there may be some required use of an execute flag and/or piping 2>, but I haven't been successful in playing with those and was hoping someone with a better acumen may be able to help.

Comment: From your comment below *I tried this almost exactly earlier and it produces no results*. Yes, I can imagine. I can't imagine a good case for having any file that is owned by `root` to have `777` permissions. So just run the `find` part of you command with the `2> /dev/null`. You may not be getting any files back. Maybe you can go in and deliberately change one? BUT the real problem, is that you need `xargs` to arrange any found files as input targets to grep. Search here for `[bash] xargs` and see many examples of this very helpful utility. OR read about the `-exec` option to `find`.GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

The "permission denied" message is written to stderr by `find`, so you can discard messages from stderr by forwarding them to `/dev/null`.

```
find / -user root -perm 777 2> /dev/null | grep "phrase to be found"
```

should do the trick, where `2>` is the redirection for stderr.

Comment: It may be due to this being a virtual environment, I believe I tried this almost exactly earlier and it produces no results.

Answer (score 0):

As [shellter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) pointed out, in your example you are asking grep to search for the phrase against the filenames themselves, not the contents of those files. I think what you are looking for is:

```
grep -Rsl "phrase to be found" /
```

The output will be a list of file names that have "phrase to be found" somewhere in their contents, but only for files you have permission to read. To read all files you need to run the same command as root.